# Could not able to change the width of snackbar using material 1.5.0

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-snackbar, snackbar

Could not able to change the width of the snackbar when migrated material design from 1.3.0 to 1.5.0.

Using below code :

```
val contentLayoutParams = snackBar.view.layoutParams as FrameLayout.LayoutParams
contentLayoutParams.width = getDimen(anchorView, R.dimen.snackBar_width)
```

Comment: Try to update snackbar's layout params after setting width like `snackBar.view.layoutParams = contentLayoutParams`

Comment: @QuarK yes, we did. but not working as expected.